# Simple modals in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, sass

Recently I was looking for some really simple modal/popup solution in vanilla JS, but nothing popped. So I wrote mine component. It works great so far, have all the options I need, but I don't know if I can improve the code itself.

JS:

```
/* A very simple modal component
You can close the modal either with `esc` key, hitting the "Close" button
or simply clicking anywhere on the page except the said modal.
Apart from this, you can open your modal with url using it's id as a hash,
eg: http://localhost#modal/loginModal
*/

import HelpMe from '../helpers/helpers';
const __ = new HelpMe();

export default class Modal {
  constructor() {
    require('./modal.scss');

    this.modals = document.querySelectorAll('modal-window');
    this.classNames = 'modal';
    this.activeClassName = 'modal--active';

    this.modalTriggers = document.querySelectorAll('[modal-trigger]');

    this.format();

    __.onEvents([window], 'load hashchange', () => { this.listenForHash(); });
  }

  format() {
    __.forEach(this.modals, (modal) => {
      const title = modal.getAttribute('title');

      modal.classList.add(this.classNames);

      modal.setAttribute('id', __.slug(title)); /* Created ID */

      this.createHTML(modal, title) /* Creating inner html */
    });
  }

  wrap(item, title, content) {
    item.innerHTML = `
<div class="modal__wrapper">
  <button class="modal__close" modal-close></button>
  <h4 class="modal__title">${title}</h4>
  <div class="modal__content">${content}</strong></div>
</div>
    `;
  }

  createHTML(modal, title) {
    const inner = modal.innerHTML; /* Get current content */
    this.wrap(modal, title, inner);

    this.listenForClick();
    this.listenForClose();
  }

  setHistory(id = null) {
    if (id) {
      window.history.pushState(null, null, `${document.location.origin}#modal/${id}`);
    } else {
      window.history.pushState(null, null, document.location.origin);
    }
  }

  open(modal) {
    this.close();

    document.getElementById(modal).classList.add(this.activeClassName);
    this.setHistory(modal);
  }

  close(modal = null) {
    if (modal) {
      document.getElementById(modal).classList.remove(this.activeClassName);
    } else {
      __.forEach(this.modals, (modal) => {
        modal.classList.remove(this.activeClassName);
      });
    }

    this.setHistory();
  }

  listenForClose() {
    // Closing with button
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[modal-close]');

    __.forEach(buttons, (button) => {
      button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.close(button.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute('id'));
      });
    });

    // Closing with esc button
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (k) => {
      if (k.keyCode === 27) this.close();
    });

    // Closing with clicking on body
    document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      if (e.target.parentNode.classList.value.indexOf('modal') === -1
          && e.target.hasAttribute('modal-trigger') === false) {
        this.close();
      }
    });
  }

  listenForClick() {
    __.forEach(this.modalTriggers, (trigger) => {
      trigger.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const modal = trigger.getAttribute('modal-trigger');
        this.open(modal);
      });
    });
  }

  listenForHash() {
    const hash = window.location.hash;

    if (hash && hash.indexOf('modal/') > -1) {
      this.open(hash.replace('#modal/', ''));
    } else {
      this.close();
    }
  }
}
```

SCSS:

```
@import 'base/vars';

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, calc(-50vh - 200%));
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 80vw;
  max-height: 80vh;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: $transition-time transform $transition-fluid,
              $transition-time opacity $transition-fluid;

  &--active {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  &__wrapper {
    position: relative;
  }

  &__close {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    outline: 0;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:after,
    &:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 5%;
      width: 90%;
      height: 1px;
      background: black;
    }

    &:after { transform: rotate(45deg); }
    &:before { transform: rotate(-45deg); }
  }
}
```

Please ignore the `HelpMe` class, it's just a collection of snippets I use often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import HelpMe from '../helpers/helpers';
const __ = new HelpMe();
```

This doesn't tell me what `HelpMe` is unless I look for it. Same can be said for `__`. We don't know what it is. It's not like jQuery or Underscore where they have been known for quite a while to use `$` and `_`, respectively. Best if you just named it `Helper`.

```
__.forEach
```

Not sure why you need this. `array.forEach` already exists in ES5. I assume this is for looping through array-like structures. Most array-like structures can be turned into a proper array with `Array.prototype.slice`.

```
export default class Modal {
```

This is misleading. `Modal` is a class and the name is singular. But it looks like what it does is collect all modal HTML and launch all of them with methods. It behaves like... a singleton. You can either:

1. Have `Modal` handle just one modal per instance, based on constructor configuration.

Expanding a bit on point #1, you export a class that holds a state of a single modal. The idea is that your modal instance knows about just one modal setup. It's your typical OOP stuff, object holding config and state for a single instance, and has methods to manipulate that.

```
export default function Modal(config){
  // stuff
}

// Usage

import Modal from 'path/to/modal/module';

var modal = new Modal({ element: '#modal-template' });

modal.open();
modal.close();
```

2. Export the module with global modal handling functions instead of a class.

Expanding a bit on point #2, the idea is that your module will not export an instantiatable class. Instead, all the module will have are a collection of functions. This operates much closely to how I see your code does it (call function, give directions, operate based on it), but throws away the idea of classes and one instance working on multiple modals.

```
export function createModal(){/* creates an object that holds a modal */}

export function openModal(modal){/* accept modal, open it */}

export function closeModal(modal){/* accept modal, close it */}

// Usage
import ModalFunctions from 'path/to/modal/module';

var modal = ModalFunctions.createModal({/* config */});
openModal(modal);
closeModal(modal);
```

The module isn't exporting a class and you operate it like you o. It's just a bunch of functions that create and handle modals.

```
open(modal) {
  this.close();

  document.getElementById(modal).classList.add(this.activeClassName);
  this.setHistory(modal);
}
```

Instead of fetching the elements on every call, why not store references to the DOM elements when you create the `Modal` instance? This way, you can avoid the overhead of DOM fetching.

```
this.close(button.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute('id'));
```

You are hardcoding the structure of your traversal to 2 ancestors up. You are restricting the flexibility of your modal markup. Consider using delegation, attaching the handlers on the top-most element of your modal and listen for descendant element events.

```
transform: translate(-50%, calc(-50vh - 200%));
```

A neat trick to center modals is to create 2 nested divs. The outer one would have `display:table`. The inner one will have `display:table-cell`. Set the `vertical-align` of an element inside that inner div to `middle` and margin to `0 auto` to center it both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Like I said earlier, `HelpMe` is just a class I am still writing and not really suitable for review. 

Can you explain what did you mean in point `2`, exporting with global modal handling functions? IIFE?

Also, can you tell me more about storing DOM reference? Is it just a array of every element?